# Need a format for Excel to datetime in milliseconds ,datetime datetime

Tags: sql, excel, datetime, format, milliseconds

I want SQL server data for datetime column in Excel with milliseconds , but 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000' is giving my milliseconds as 000 in the cell. Like "2022/03/05 12:35:46.000" .I need a format that works for my data?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be able to get the miliseconds if you multiply the date by 86400000. So, as example, 8th July 2022 would be 3866400000000 miliseconds

Comment: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000 works fine for me, E.g 2022/07/06 01:24:42.353. Do you have decimal separator set to , rather than . in Regional Settings?